# how to use progress dialog in base adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, progressdialog

i have a custom listview with some textviews and a button. On button click i want to save the listview values to server, to do this task i'm using asyntask but my code crashed on pregress dialog. i'm having problem how to pass activity's instance for using progress dialog

```
  public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

  Context context;
  public arrayList<Planning> arraylist;
  private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
  public PlanningList_activity planActivity;
  public ListView mListview;
  Db_sqlite databaseHelper;

  public ListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Plan>  arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.planArraylist = plan0Arraylist;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)      context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    databaseHelper = new Db_sqlite(context);
 }
 @Override
public int getCount() {
    return planArraylist.size();
}

@Override
public Planning getItem(int arg0) {
    return planArraylist.get(arg0);
} 

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}


 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_lv_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();


            holder.tvdrCode = (TextView convertView.findViewById(R.id.Plan_no);
            holder.tvDrName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doc_name);
            holder.tvterrcode= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mon);
            holder.tvAdr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adr);
            holder.tvClassDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.class_desc);
            holder.tvspeciality = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ff_code);
            holder.tvAreaName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area_name);
            holder.tvShift = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shift);
            holder.btn_visited =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            holder.btn_visited.setTag(position);
            holder.btn_visited.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } 

        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Planning p = planArraylist.get(position);
        holder.tvdrCode.setText(p.getDocCode());
        holder.tvDrName.setText(p.getDocName());
        holder.tvterrcode.setText(p.getTerrCode());
        holder.tvAdr.setText(p.getAdr());
        holder.tvClassDesc.setText(p.getClassDesc());
        holder.tvspeciality.setText(p.getSP());
        holder.tvAreaName.setText(p.getAreaName());
        holder.tvShift.setText(p.getMornEven());

        return convertView;
    }

     static class ViewHolder {
         TextView tvdrCode;
         TextView tvDrName;
         TextView tvterrcode;
         TextView tvAdr;
         TextView tvClassDesc;
         TextView tvspeciality;
         TextView tvAreaName;
         TextView tvShift;
         Button btn_visited;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `context` is `null` . use `mContext` which you are passing in `SaveDCR` class constructor for creating progress bar:

```
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
          progressDialog.setMessage("Saving...");
          progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
          progressDialog.show();
          Log.e( "sending dvr to sqlite","yes"); 

      }
```

And from Button click pass context as:

```
new SaveDCR(v.getContext()).execute(dvr);
```

Comment: @konainali: use `new SaveDCR(v.getContext()).execute(dvr); `

Comment: now i'm getting exception " unable to add window, null in not for an application

Comment: @konainali: what you  are passing as first parameter in `PlannningListViewAdapter` class constructor when creating object ?

Comment: @konainali: i mean it's `getApplicationContext()` ?